# “Get something to work” vs ”Get something working”

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs

Having the following sentences:

> I did not get it to work.
>    I did not get it working.

Is there a difference in the meaning? What usage of "GET" is this (I would be happy for dictionary entry reference). IMHO the first one is "cause" (like *I got him to do that*). But I cannot find a reference to "get sth + ing".

Comment: The first sentence is not grammatical in English. It should be “I did not get it _to_ work”. I would say that ‘cause’ is the meaning in the second as well: both are a type of factitive or causative phrasing. More specifically than that, though, I do not have any established name or analysis for it readily available. I suspect @JohnLawler will, though, if he sees this.

Comment: You are right, I accidentally omitted "to".

Comment: I must wonder aloud if user970696 is aware of the sister site for [ell.SE], and if the question might have been a better fit for that site instead.

Comment: @J.R. well but this is related just to the "get + to/ing". I do understand the usage of infinitives in general.

Comment: Just to be clear, I have no problem with this question, but there are still many folks unaware of the ELL site.

Comment: Both answers are grammatical, and similar in meaning.  A difference not yet mentioned in answers is that the first form is common and natural English, while the other is unnatural and unlikely to be used.

Comment: @jwpat7 What's your basis for saying that the second form "is unnatural and unlikely to be used". I'm not clear whether you're saying that *get it working* is not used or *didn't get it working* is not used. As JBJ says in a comment below my answer, *couldn't get it working* is probably more common, but I see no problem with any of those phrases in BrE.

Comment: @TrevorD, I realize that [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+it+working%2Cget+it+to+work%2Cis+it+working%2Cit+is+working%2Cdidn%27t+get+it+working%2Ccouldn%27t+get+it+working&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) shows that *get it working* actually appears in print, but to my ear “I didn't get it working” and “I couldn't get it working” sound awkward and unnatural. It seems to me that JBJ's comment says those alternatives are awkward. The ngrams link in first sentence shows no occurrences of either. I don't have other evidence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There *can* be a subtle difference.

If I were *creating* something, e.g. writing some new programming code; putting some electrical or mechanical components together to achieve a particular objective; installing and setting up a new TV set for the first time <sup>[1]</sup>; then, if unsuccessful, I might say **"I didn't get it *to work*"** or **"I can't/couldn't get it *to work*"** <sup>[1]</sup>. (It had *never* worked, because it was new.)

If I were *repairing* something that *had previously worked* (e.g. repairing a previously working TV set <sup>[1]</sup>) and the repair was unsuccessful, then I would probably say **"I didn't/can't/couldn't get it *working*"**. (It had *previously* worked.)

Note that these are *subtle* differences, and I do not mean to imply that the expressions and scenarios are necessarily always used that way around, not that it would be wrong to use them the other way around.

<sub><sup>[1]</sup> Thanks to Janus Bahs Jacquet, whose comments contributed some examples and other input to my revised answer.</sub>

Comment: I _think_ I can see the difference you are mentioning here, but I have to admit that I could also easily imagine “I didn’t get it to work” being used in the second of your scenarios. If the auxiliary is switched from ‘did’ to ‘could’, the difference becomes slightly sharper to my ears: “I can’t/couldn’t get it to work” sounds more like someone trying to set up a new TV set for the first time, for example, than like someone repairing a previously working one—it would be more awkward for the latter case than “I didn’t get it to work” would be, at least.

Comment: I agree (and meant to say) that the first expression *could* be used in the second scenario. I also agree that setting up a TV set is a good example for the first scenario - where you had not previously had it working (either at all or in that scenario). That is sort of the thing I had in mind when talking of "putting some electrical [or electronic] ... components together to achieve a particular objective"; i.e. you're putting something together for the first time rather than fixing something that stopped working. I just couldn't think of a good example previously.  cont'd ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Cont'd ... As regards "can't/couldn't" v. "didn't" I also agree: I was just concentrating on the *to work/working* bit rather than the verb!  If you've no objections, I'll amend my answer to incorporate your ideas, when I have a little more time.

Answer (score 1):

"I got it to work." - It is now capable of being utilized. It worked at least momentarily, either long enough to complete a task or just to prove functionality.

"I got it working." - Some amount of continuousness is implied. This is  the same as "got it to work", but with additional information. You not only got the fridge to begin operating but it was left to run for some duration and probably continues to run now.

"I could not get it to work" - It did not function after your efforts, not even momentarily. This was possibly intended to be a momentary single-use instance, but there is no information in the sentence about possible continuousness.

"I could not get it working". - The same as above *but* you probably intended to leave it in a state of continuous operation, as you would a fridge. At the least, you envisioned it needing to be in a state of functionality​ for some duration so people could continuously tap into its utility.

Answer (score -1):

There's a difference between the two. The first uses the infinitive while the second uses the gerund form of the verb. Now this might not be a good example to illustrate the difference between the two, but here's another example that clearly illustrates the difference:

> I stopped smoking. Here you stopped the action of smoking. You no longer smoke.
>
> I stopped to smoke. Here you stopped first wanted to smoke. The smoking hadn't happened yet.

In your examples there's not much of a difference in meaning between the two. The second seems to be more common than the first, at least in AmE. For example, if you had a printer that didn't work, the first would refer to the process of getting it working, while the second would refer to its action, which is functioning. But that's really splitting hairs.

Comment: Thanks but I asked particularly about GET to do/doing as the dictionaries usually mention "to cause something, as in "to get the fire to burn". I do not exactly understand the usage of "GET" in these sentences.